# Overfitting Issue On a variation of ZF-net

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am training a CNN on imagenet-2012 dataset, but the model keeps overfitting(Valiation Error rate: top1: 49%, top5: 25%, Training Error rate: top1:25%, top5: 8%. trained on GTX1080ti after 600k training steps (about 5 days)). the architecture is based on ZF-net but adds batch norm:

```
     x_input = feed_key['input']
bn_training = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.bool, shape=(), name='bn_training')
with tf.name_scope('ZF_conv1'):
    w_conv1 = tf.get_variable(name='conv1_kernel', shape=[7, 7, 3, 96], dtype=tf.float32)
    h_conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(x_input, w_conv1, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
with tf.name_scope('ZF_bn1'):
    bn1 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(h_conv1, training=bn_training)
with tf.name_scope('ZF_relu1'):
    h_active1 = tf.nn.relu(bn1)

with tf.name_scope('ZF_pool1'):
    h_pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(h_active1, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

with tf.name_scope('ZF_conv2'):
    w_conv2 = tf.get_variable(name='conv2_kernel', shape=[5, 5, 96, 256], dtype=tf.float32)
    h_conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(h_pool1, w_conv2, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
with tf.name_scope('ZF_bn2'):
    bn2 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(h_conv2, training=bn_training)
with tf.name_scope('ZF_relu2'):
    h_active2 = tf.nn.relu(bn2)

with tf.name_scope('ZF_pool2'):
    h_pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(h_active2, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

with tf.name_scope('ZF_conv3'):
    w_conv3 = tf.get_variable(name='conv3_kernel', shape=[3, 3, 256, 384], dtype=tf.float32)
    h_conv3 = tf.nn.conv2d(h_pool2, w_conv3, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
with tf.name_scope('ZF_bn3'):
    bn3 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(h_conv3, training=bn_training)
with tf.name_scope('ZF_relu3'):
    h_active3 = tf.nn.relu(bn3)

with tf.name_scope('ZF_conv4'):
    w_conv4 = tf.get_variable(name='conv4_kernel', shape=[3, 3, 384, 384], dtype=tf.float32)
    h_conv4 = tf.nn.conv2d(h_active3, w_conv4, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
with tf.name_scope('ZF_bn4'):
    bn4 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(h_conv4, training=bn_training)
with tf.name_scope('ZF_relu4'):
    h_active3 = tf.nn.relu(bn4)

with tf.name_scope('ZF_conv5'):
    w_conv5 = tf.get_variable(name='conv5_kernel', shape=[3, 3, 384, 256], dtype=tf.float32)
    h_conv5 = tf.nn.conv2d(h_active3, w_conv5, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

with tf.name_scope('ZF_bn5'):
    bn5 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(h_conv5, training=bn_training)
with tf.name_scope('ZF_relu5'):
    h_active5 = tf.nn.relu(bn5)

feed_key['bn_training'] = bn_training
```

Followed by two FC layer:

```
fc1 = tf.layers.dense(low_out_flat,
                      units=4096,
                      activation=tf.nn.relu,
                      name='zffc1')

keep_prob1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob1')
dropout1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, keep_prob1, name='zfdrop1')

fc2 = tf.layers.dense(dropout1,
                      units=4096,
                      activation=tf.nn.relu,
                      name='zffc2')

keep_prob2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob2')
dropout2 = tf.nn.dropout(fc2, keep_prob2, name='zfdrop2')

feed_key['keep_prob1'] = keep_prob1
feed_key['keep_prob2'] = keep_prob2
```

Finally compute the cross entropy:

```
 gt_labels = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int64, shape=[None])
logits = tf.layers.dense(model.last_layer, units=1000, name='imagenet_logits')

with tf.name_scope('imagenet_cross_entropy'):
    entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=gt_labels, logits=logits)
with tf.name_scope('imagenet_loss'):
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(entropy)
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    train_op = training_methods.optimizer.minimize(loss=loss, global_step=training_methods.global_step)
```

For The Data Preprocessing at training, I followed the paper:[Visualizing and Understanding Convolutional Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.2901)

> Each RGB image was preprocessed by resizing the smallest dimension to 256, cropping the center 256x256 region, subtracting the per-pixel mean (across all images) and then using 10 different sub-crops of size 224x224 (corners + center with(out) horizontal flips).

(remark: I calculated the image mean across the whole training dataset by first resizing it to 224*224, not 256*256. so I subtract the image mean after sub-cropping image to 224*224. I thought it is not a problem)
When Testing, I just resize the image to 224*224(Is that a problem?)

Optimizer:Adam with initial learning rate 0.001 epsilon 0.1, 
drop out rate was set to 0.5.
lastly, I use `tf.variance_scaling_initializer()` to initialize all weights

The ZF-net paper reported their result was Testing error rate: top1:36.7% top5:15.3% so this is way off my result, but I can't find where is wrong

Comment: Have you made a plot of your training and test error rate every epoch? It might be that you reach their results and then start overfitting afterwards.

Comment: yes, I draw the plot by using the tensor board, and I never hit the spot(the result in their paper), but I evaluate the model every 100 training step by sampling a minibatch(size of 128) in the testing set

Comment: sorry, I evaluate the model on the validation set not testing set

Comment: Hm, there's a lot of things it could be then. I'd try comparing your code to this (https://github.com/rainer85ah/Papers2Code/blob/master/ZFNet/ZFNet.py) and see what's different. Use Tensorflow's debugger to step through the code and see exactly where the results change if necessary.

Comment: I have revised my code similar to that you proposed (remove some batch norm, only change the lrn norm to batch norm) now I'm training this model, it seems(after two days training) little more promising(too much batch norm is detrimental?).

Comment: Honestly, I've never had batch norm improve any of my models. I know it's considered a *standard*, but every time I try it it just screws the performance of the model up in some way or another. I usually just use L1 or L2 regulation.

Comment: sometimes researchers in this field do not know what they are talking about, in the batch norm case, they don't  know why it is working, they don't even know what is 'variance shifting' (do not have a mathematical definition) and they all overfitting the "standard" data sets "(Image net, CIFAR-10 etc)

Answer (score 0):

the thing is when I evaluate the model I just resize the image to 224*224, it is different from the training data processing(crop image to 224*224), so the probability distribution of validation set is kind of different from the training set(different manifolds), and originally I thought it is not a big deal and the changes in distribution would not be dramatic.
after I revised that, there is a significant drop in the validation error

Comment: but the overfitting issue is not gone completely